# Is "going on" a phrasal verb in "What's going on?"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is "going on" a phrasal verb in the question "What's going on?"

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Agree about what?

Comment: I just wanted to know if 'going on' is a phrasal verb or not.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, Yes. To ***go on*** can be an ordinary "verb + preposition", as in *I go on the bus to get to work*, or *Superman's underpants go on the outside of his costume*. But it's also a [phrasal verb](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/phrasalverbterm.htm) with several different meanings, including these as given by [usingenglish.com](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/go+on.html)...

> 1: **Continue**
>   *He **went on** and **on** talking and I was so bored.*
>
> 2: **Happen**
>   *There are loads of people out in the street; what's **going on**?*
>
> 3: **Start doing or taking something**
>    *She **went on** the pill when she met him*
>
> 4: **Be guided**
>    *The investigators have no clues to **go on***
>
> 5: **Be nearly** (a certain period of time)
>    *It's **going on** ten years since we met*
>
> 6: **Progress**
>    *They asked me how the project was **going on***
>
> 7: **Spend money**
>    *Most of my salary **goes on** my mortgage repayments*
>
> 8: **Start working** (electric/electronic equipment)
>    *The alarm **goes on** when you close the front door.*

Note that depending on your *exact* definition of "phrasal verb" you might include other senses (or exclude one or more of the above).

Comment: I think the example 4 in your answer could be rewritten as "*The investigators have no clues **on which** to go*".  Am I wrong?

Comment: Same applies to the example 5, methinks.  And the example 7, in which '*on*' is a simple preposition for the object, and not part of the phrasal verb.

Comment: @Victor: Your rewrite for #4 is certainly "credible", but I must be honest and point out that whereas, say, *Just give me something to go on* is perfectly ordinary, you might raise a few eyebrows if you rephrased to *Just give me something on which to go*. And as to whether all these examples are really "phrasal verbs" by *your* definition, I'm just reporting what that particular website cites (I myself wouldn't call #7 or #8 "typical" examples, but the term itself doesn't have a single unambiguous meaning, as I pointed out).

Comment: I think their ('usingenglish.com') definition of a phrasal verb is a stable combination that does not allow any word to be put between the verb and the preposition.  Ex.7 fails that, for sure, since it's possible to write "*Most of my salary goes **directly** on my mortgage repayments*".  Is there something I misconstrued?

Comment: @Victor: I think that's *your* definition. The page I linked to includes a further link to [*their* definition(s)](http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/phrasal-verb.html), wherein they separately identify "inseparable" phrasal verbs, and both "optional" and "obligatory" "separable" ones. I don't see any point in getting hung up over the precise details of terminology, but it *is* useful to learn when/how you can split the elements of any given phrasal verb.

Comment: Thanks for this information, it's valuable.  Note, however, that they are talking about placing the object between the verb and the particle, not an adverb.

Comment: @@Victor: To the extent that I recognize "phrasal verb" as a useful label, I think one crucial distinction is that ***to look after** (= to care for*) is a "prepositional verb". You can tell that because *We looked after the children* and *We looked after them* are both fine, but *We looked the children after* and *We looked them after* are unacceptable. But consider a "true" phrasal verb: *She **gave away** all her money*, where *She **gave** all her money **away*** and *She **gave** it **away*** are fine, but not *She gave away **it***. It's *pronouns* that are significant here, not objects.